# ShareKit email form displays improperly

Tags: ios, email, sharekit

I'm using the ShareKit SHKMail form like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"I made this song with the VinylDreams app for iPad!" contentType:SHKURLContentTypeAudio];  
SHKMail* actionSheet = [SHKMail shareItem:item];
```

It works fine on all of our devices except one. All of our devices are iPad 2s running iOS 7. On the one device it doesn't show properly it looks like this:

[pic http://timlukens.com/sharekitemail.png](http://timlukens.com/sharekitemail.png)

The device has a mail account associated with it. The "Send to Email" does nothing. Basically, I have no idea why this would look and behave any differently on another iPad (it works fine on five others).

Comment: I also just checked on the device in question just doing:

    `MFMailComposeViewController* vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];`

And it shows an email form just fine.

Comment: Do you have [ShareKit 2](https://github.com/sharekit/sharekit)?